# How can I keep exports from stealing?

Tags: tropico-5

I'm selling gold to China through an export trade route. I'm also running two Electronics Factories, which require gold and bauxite. How do I keep the export trade route from stealing <strike>candy from a bab</strike> gold from my factories? I keep seeing the factories run low (and occasionally out) of gold.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the Trade Export, there is no other way. Just like your previous question you're trying to micromanage too much. Profits of Electronics > Gold.

**Edit:** 
If you're at the point of selling electronic goods, your island should be full blown. Meaning, this 1 commodity should not matter in the big picture. You said, you don't have enough gold to export and keep your factory(s) stocked with gold.

If you have a Contract setup, that is what is "stealing" your gold.

What kind of answer are you looking for? Tropico is not setup to micromanage, exactly how many gold units you export and how many you use in your production. If you have a trade setup and it's going to use that is a priority to export before caring about production.

Can you tell me how much you are making on Gold export vs electronics exports? I doubt it, BUT if you could, finished goods always make more money.

Profits of Electronics > Gold. Raw goods will never make as much money as finished goods. This is fact. So my answer is your best course of action, unless you find another mine somewhere on the Island that has gold.

Comment: It's not quite that simple; a factory only makes a few hundred units a month, while a dock can import/export about 1000 of any given resource in a month (3000 units/shipment, one shipment per 3 months). And the economics change again if you have great trade routes.

Comment: @paulmarshall I don't know what kind of answer you want, but that's all I got.

Comment: @Paul That same dock is selling your finished electronic goods as well, so I don't really see your point. You need to choose whether you want to export all your gold, or use it to produce electronics. If you go with the later you want to produce roughly as much gold as your factories need. Basically either build more factories or don't build as many mines.

Comment: I just checked my docks; part of my problem is that all of my docks have gold that's apparently marked for export. Seriously, there's gobs of gold (and bauxite) sitting in the docks marked for export, and my factories are frequently running out. I am seriously confused by my teamsters' priorities.